# Algorithm to merge adjacent raster datasets

Tags: raster, algorithm, image-mosaic

I am trying to figure out how to merge adjacent raster datasets.
Is there any clear algorithms (may be a pseudo code)?

Comment: How are you determining the source raster?  Is it a selected raster, from a list, all in a directory, etc.?

Comment: It's a collection of JPG images in one directory. each of them has a world file (.jpgw) and a projection file (.prj).

Comment: Do you want to find the rasters on all potential sides (ie: 4 sides along the raster edge)

Comment: yes, it's the situation what I'm dealing with.
It's some kind of mosaiced images that i want to merge in one image.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are looking to merge all the images from a folder you can do a two step process.

```
1) Use command prompt to make a directory list file [ dir c:\temp\*.jpg /b /s >c:\temp\imagelist.txt ]

2) Using FWTools run gdal_merge [ gdal_merge -o c:\temp\mosaic.tif -q -v --optfile c:\temp\imagelist.txt ]
```

This will make a file of all the images in a directory, and then mosaic the files into an output file.

Comment: Thank you very much,
What I was searching for is an algorithm to embed in my gis application. However, this tool seems to be useful and suits my needs.
Thank you

Comment: GDAL can be accessed through its C / C++ API, or the bindings which exist for it in numerous languages.